# Accessing GPS within Service? Android/Java

Tags: java, android, gps

I am trying to run a background service that will pull the latest GPS coordinates and then post them to a server via a PHP script.

I have this working in the sense that it posts the information to the server, and it will do so in the background (as a service).

In the snippet below it is always false (location == null).

I am new to Java programming and I don't think that I am doing this correctly. Should I have a variable that I am updating whenever there is a GPS update and then read that from my background Service?

Should I have the GPS functions separate from this Service class all together and call it when I need the data? Or should I be using an AsyncTask ?

Sorry if the questions are noobish, Java is rather complex compared to PHP.

Thank you.

```
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    String Long = null;
    String Lat = null;

    if (location != null) {
    Long =  String.format("%1$s",location.getLongitude());
    Lat = String.format("%1$s", location.getLatitude());
     } 
     else{
     Long = "error";
     Lat = "error";

     }
```

Below is the full code.

```
    public class UpdaterService extends Service {
      private static final String TAG = UpdaterService.class.getSimpleName();
      private Updater updater;

      private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
      private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds
      protected LocationManager locationManager;

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        updater = new Updater();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, 
                new MyLocationListener()
                );

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");

      }


        private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }

        }


    @Override
      public synchronized void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
          // Start the updater
        if (!updater.isRunning()) {
          updater.start();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "onStart'd");
      }


      @Override
      public synchronized void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the updater
        if (updater.isRunning()) {
          updater.interrupt();
        }
        updater = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy'd");
      }

      // ///// Updater Thread
      class Updater extends Thread {
        private static final long DELAY = 10000; // one minute
        private boolean isRunning = false;

        public Updater() {
          super("Updater");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
          isRunning = true;
          while (isRunning) {
            try {

              Log.d(TAG, "Updater run'ing");
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mydomain.com/save.php");

              try {
                // Add your data
                  Log.d(TAG, "Working..");

                  Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                 String Long = null;
                 String Lat = null;

                  if (location != null) {
                     Long =  String.format("%1$s",location.getLongitude());
                     Lat = String.format("%1$s", location.getLatitude());
                  } 
                  else{
                    Long = "error";
                    Lat = "error";

                  }


                 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lid", "1"));
                  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",Lat));
                  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", Long));
                  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                  // Execute HTTP Post Request
                  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


              } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              }


              // Sleep
              Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // Interrupted
              isRunning = false;
            }
          } // while
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
          return this.isRunning;
        }

      }

    }
```

Below is the Main Activity:

```
    public class Main extends Activity {
              /** Called when the activity is first created. */
          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          }

          @Override
          protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

          }

          // /////// Menu Stuff

          @Override
          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.itemPrefs:
           //     startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class));
             break;
            case R.id.itemServiceStart:
              startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class));
              break;
            case R.id.itemServiceStop:
              stopService(new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class));
              break;
            }

            return true;
          }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the snippet below it is always false `(location == null)`.

If you are running your code on emulator you need to feed GPS data to emulator manually(from DDMS perspective in Eclipse).

> I am new to Java programming and I don't think that I am doing this correctly. Should I have a variable that I am updating whenever there is a GPS update and then read that from my background Service?

Yes you can do that. I have done a similar thing earlier and it works.

> Should I have the GPS functions separate from this Service class all together and call it when I need the data? Or should I be using an AsyncTask?

Nope! But it would be a nice idea if you do something like :

```
public class UpdaterService extends Service implements LocationListener{
}
```

As for the noob-ish part. No question is stupid and we are all noobs one or the other way.
Hope this helps.